# Is it possible to slow charge a 240W laptop with 65W power bank via USB C?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charging, usb-3.1-type-c

I have a Dell Precision 7750, which has a strong GPU, and therefore a power adapter with 240W.

When I'm on the road, I need to charge the laptop with a power bank. My power bank is 65W.

I want to charge the computer, even if it is very slow to charge. I don’t want to run the GPU when doing this, so probably the computer does not consume 240W but much less.

When I plug the power bank via the  USB C Thunderbolt 3 connection, nothing happens, and warning comes up that the PC is not charging.

What can I do?

Comment: It seems like the Dell Precision 7750 supports power delivery — which would allow it to charge via the USB C connection — but 65W is about 3.5 times less 240W. In my experience with MacBooks, you can always plugin power adapters that provide less wattage *but* they won’t do much. I have a MacBook Air that needs at least 29W power to share but if I plug it into an 18W adapter I get a similar “not charging message.” I would say you need at least an 240W USB power adapter to do what you wish to do.

Comment: What happens if you turn the computer off, and try to charge it then? It then doesn't consume any power, so may change slowly then.

Comment: Not all chargers are compatible with all laptops : [link](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-portable-laptop-battery-chargers-and-power-banks).

Comment: The 65W charger may overheat, an experiment on your part.

Comment: @LPChip It does not charge it when it off

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I didn't understand. Can you charge with low adapter?

Comment: @BestR A lower power adapter will not charge. It will simply be drained into the battery in the laptop as being used. Meaning if you have — let’s say — 1 hour of charge left on your laptop, if you plug in a lower power power bank like you have it will extend the that one 1 hour to  maybe 1 hour and 2 minutes. It doesn't charge but it gives the device another power source that will drain instead when the laptop battery final goes 0%.

Comment: @BestR Giacomo1968's comment makes sense, as Dell uses a communication line between the charging port and the power brick's PCB _(the center pin on the DC jack)_. While unrelated, you can switch off the discrete GPU by switching to the integrated GPU via a function key _(on my Alienware 18, it's `Fn`+`F5`)_. While the communication line can by bypassed by soldering a resistor between two pins on the microchip that handles this communication next to the DC jack on the motherboard, this is only recommended if wanting to use non-Dell approved power bricks delivering the same voltage/amperage.

Comment: @BestR _(Cont'd...)_ That being said, it's unwise to try and power a device from a power source that doesn't meet the minimum wattage required by the device, as this thermally stresses the power source _(e.g. if using the power bank with the laptop on, it would be best to only use the integrated graphics in lieu of the discrete GPU, and to continuously monitor the heat output by the power bank to ensure it doesn't get hot to the touch from the higher impedance that occurs when trying to pull more current than a power source is able to output)_

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 90W small Dell charger when travelling and it covers the needs without problems. If you are not 3D modelling too much or doing stuff that requires high CPU usage, the 90W charger is enough to feed the laptop and also to charge attached phone. With 65W charger, which is only a bit smaller than 90W version, sometimes the battery level goes down as it is not able to fully cover the running laptop. On the other hand if you are only browsing internet, dealing with emails and you keep your screen on low level of backlight and select system behavior to "energy saving" setting, then even the 65W charger will be enough for you.